# Bad Performance issue for LazyVStack , SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have got a view with like 100 rows:

```
ForEach(moodEntries.reversed(), id: \.self) { entry in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.activeMoodForModal = moodEntries.lastIndex(of: entry) ?? 0
                            self.showMoodModal.toggle()
                        }) {
                            MoodTableViewCard(entry: entry)
                        }

                    }.sheet(item: $activeMoodForModal) { item in
                        MoodEntryModalView(entry: moodEntries[item], saveNote: {
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                    }
```

The performance is really bad: when I open this view the whole app freezes for 3 seconds on a simulator. If I change `ForEach` to `List` everything works fine so I suppose lazy loading will solve my problem. But I don't want to mess with List so I tried to put all the code mentioned above inside the `LazyVStack { }` but it didn't help: the code performs as bad as before. Is `LazyVStack` really so much worse than `List` or maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example? One can be said definitely - move `.sheet` out of dynamic content, because now you have as many sheets as `moodEntries` count.

Answer (score 6):

`LazyVStack` does *not* reuse cells at all, so no matter what you do - it will still lag on scrolling. If you have more elements than fit the screen and the layout more complex than `Text("Hello")` - use `List`.

Comment: This would make sense for a LazyVStack, however LazyHStack still has these same issues.