# SwiftUI | Stop LazyVStack itemviews subview auto deallocation when scrolled outside of screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following scenario:

Inside my LazyVGrid, I have some items (`Rectangle`) and every rectangle has a further subview (`OverlayRectangle`).

Now when I scroll these items outside of the screen, they get deallocated. As you can see here, the `onAppear` animation happens again!

[image]

I don't want that to happen.
Is there anything I can do besides replacing the `LazyVStack` with a normal one?

Here is the demo-code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .overlay(OverlayRectangle(index: i))
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private struct OverlayRectangle: View {
    
        @State private var appear = false
        var index: Int
        
        var body: some View {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .overlay(Text("\(index)").foregroundColor(.white))
                .opacity(appear ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                .onAppear { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) { appear = true } }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not really sure what do you try to do here... it behaves exactly as you coded. I think you misunderstood the nature of LazyVStack - it reuses views, so once one row disappeared from top that view is used to render next appeared at bottom, and vice versa.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Comment: I think I was just wondering since this only happens to child views of each item view.

Comment: In fact it's stated that lazy stacks do NOT reuse cells: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283117/129202